# How can we build a dependent dropdown using chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I would like to build a dependent dropdown with search feature (I used chosen for the search feature). If any country is selected from the first dropdown the second dropdown should reflect the updated choices related to the first selection.

Example: if India is selected in the first dropdown the second dropdown should have "gurgaon, chennai, bangalore"

```js
$(".dropdown1").chosen({
  maximumSelectionLength: 2,
  max_selected_options: 5
});

$(".dropdown2").chosen({
  maximumSelectionLength: 2,
  max_selected_options: 5
});

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.dropdown1').on('change', dependentDropdown);
  $('.dropdown1').on('change', myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("dropdown1").value)
}

function dependentDropdown() {
  var $countriesDropdown = $("#dropdown1"),
    $citiesDropdown = $("#dropdown2");
  
  $countriesDropdown.on("change", function() {
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    console.log(_rel);
    
    $citiesDropdown.find("option").attr("style", "");
    $citiesDropdown.val("");
    
    if (!_rel) return $citiesDropdown.prop("disabled", true);
    
    $citiesDropdown.find("[rel~='" + _rel + "']").show();
    $citiesDropdown.prop("disabled", false);
  });
}
```

```css
.whole-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dp {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" />

<p>Select a value from the list:</p>

<div class="whole-container">
  <div class="dp">
    <select id="dropdown1" class="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" multiple="false" style="width: 200px;">
      <option value="india">india</option>
      <option value="usa">usa</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dp">
    <select name="dropdown2" class="dropdown2" id="dropdown2" multiple="false" style="width: 200px;" disabled="disabled">
      <option rel="india" value="gurgaon">gurgaon</option>
      <option rel="india" value="chennai">chennai</option>
      <option rel="india" value="bangalore">bangalore</option>
      <option rel="usa" value="waltham">waltham</option>
      <option rel="usa" value="chicago">chicago </option>
      <option rel="usa" value="wasgington d c">washington d c</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Protip: Use console logs, not alerts. Alerts are a real pain because you have to dismiss them.

Comment: You've done a fairly good job of explaining your goal, but not the problem. What's going wrong? What debugging have you done? If you haven't learned to use breakpoints in the browser to inspect values, now's the time.

Comment: You probably just need to run the update trigger for Chosen. `$citiesDropdown.trigger('chosen:updated')` after making any changes to the dropdown.

Comment: You also need to rethink your logic. `.dropdown` and `#dropdown1` are the same element, and you're creating a change handler _on each change_ of that element. I suggest doing a little flowchart to see things more clearly.

Comment: I recommend naming your elements properly instead of calling them `dropdown1` `dropdown2` etc. In your code you reference them as `countries` and `cities`, why not just make that their ID as well?

Comment: I agree with that, and also name your functions intuitively. Good code is easy to read and understand.